# Setting the Delegate for Multiple UIWebViews on the same ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have two UIWebViews, one to handle normal files and one to handle PDFs (which opens as an overlay, on top of the other web view).

Both webviews are setup as below:

```
//Options for webView
webView.delegate = self;
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
for (id subview in webView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;

//Options for pdfViewer
pdfViewer.delegate = self;
pdfViewer.scalesPageToFit = YES;
for (id subview in pdfViewer.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
```

the line `pdfViewer.delegate = self;` causes my app some trouble. I have a delegate method I'm making use of `webViewDidFinishLoad` and so I need the `delegate` of both views to be `self`. If it's not set, i.e. I comment it out. The PDF loads in the view, but the `webViewDidFinishLoad` doesn't fire, as you'd expect. However, if I re-activate the line, the PDF doesn't load into the view at all. Is there some sort of clash happening? Can I assign multiple `UIWebViews` `delegate = self`?

Update:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize webView;

//these two just appear to show the page is loading.
@synthesize loadingView;
@synthesize linkLoadView;

//pdfViewer is contained within topView
@synthesize topView;
@synthesize pdfViewer;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];    

linkLoadView.alpha=0.0;
[topView removeFromSuperview];

//Options for 
webView.delegate = self;
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
for (id subview in webView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;

//Options for 
//pdfViewer.delegate = self;
pdfViewer.scalesPageToFit = YES;
for (id subview in pdfViewer.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;

NSURL *filePath = [NSURL URLWithString:@"*webaddress*/index.html"];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:filePath];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;  {
    /* Add Content Loading Banner */
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
       [self.view addSubview:linkLoadView];
       linkLoadView.alpha = 1.0;
    }

    /* Handle PDF Opening */
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
    if([urlString rangeOfString:@".pdf"].location == NSNotFound){
        return true;
    } else {
        NSURL *filePath = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:filePath];
        [pdfViewer loadRequest:requestObj];

        [self.view addSubview:topView];
        [self.view addSubview:linkLoadView];

        return false;
    }

}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView{
    NSLog(@"Fired");    
}

@end
```

Comment: what's going on in your webViewDidFinishLoad?

Comment: @mbehan at the moment it's just an NSLog. Do you think that because webView is already loaded that the webViewDidFinishLoad won't fire for pdfViewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you overriding any other methods from the UIWebView delegate like shouldLoadRequest etc....?

There is no issue with having a single delegate to multiple webviews so I am guessing that something is stopping the normal request process somewhere.

Comment: I'm using shouldStartLoadWithRequest, it's the function that decides if it's a PDF or not and thus opens it in a different webView

Comment: You are a genius, I created a variable that allowed bypassing of the PDF handling part of the shouldStartLoadWithRequest, if the PDF setup had been completed once. Cheers!